# Using ArcGIS for clustering and correlating large datasets

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, coordinates, clustering

I have a large amount of historical lightning strike data (with lat, lon and timestamp) and am trying to separate out isolated events, which aren't part of larger clusters found in thunderstorms (i.e. potentially anomalous events). I then want to see if the density/frequency of these isolated events is correlated to areas of earthquake activity (I also have a list of lat lon and timestamps for earthquake events.).

I have been trying to do this in python, but have been put on to the fact that GIS might be much better suited for the task. Could anyone tell me if this is so, and how I might go about it in a memory efficient manner?

I have access to ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop.

[image]

An example of the sort of isolated event cluster I'm looking at can be seen in the bottom left of this image. As you can see it's in a smaller group, not attached to a larger storm. Sometimes there are only 1 or 2 strikes. my initial parameters for 'closeness' will probably be 200-300km, and 2-3 hours

Comment: There are several relevant techniques e.g. clustering, Hot Spot analysis, Geoweighted regression. Which would help however depends allot on your data and whether it needs a scalar or logistic approach. How isolated are the lightning strikes of interest (in space and time) how large are the areas of earth quake activity (i.e. can one isolate individual strike-quake cases or are there many strikes within on quake zone.) An example map would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't quite sure what I needed to post. I have added an example image taken from my raw data.

Comment: I may have over simplified this in my head, You want to identify lightning strikes in earthquake zones? You could use the [select by location](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm) tool. Assuming you have your strikes and earthquake epicentres as points then you could very easily select all strikes withing 200Km of an epicentre.

Comment: No, not quite, I want to determine isolated strikes, that aren't part of large clusters (as this may mean they're anomalous). Then I want to see if there's a correlation between the density/frequency of these isolated fixes, and the presence of earthquake zones.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you are looking for lightning strikes which are isolated, by which you mean there is only one strike within a 200km radius in a given three hour period. You will then investigate whether these strikes are in earthquake zones.

Comment: That's basically the concept, although I may expand to look at as many as 3 strikes within that space-time window (as multiple strokes within a single strike are registered individually).

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to keep revising your question as advice is offered and clarifications are sought.  For questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.